# How to set mysqladmin default user & password?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

A fresh install of mysql has the defaults set to `root` and `using password: NO`. However, on my system you can run `mysqladmin ping` with success, although `mysqladmin ping -u root` will fail. This tells me that mysqladmin is reading the user/pass from somewhere.

I'm trying to re-create this on another system. I know the username and password and can successfully do `mysqladmin ping -u myuser -p 'mypass'` on my new server, but I need to set it up so that `mysqladmin ping` alone will work without needing to pass `myuser` and `mypass` explicitly.

### edit:

Here is some output demonstrating the difference between the old and new system ( the last line is the only difference):

**old server**

```
$ mysqladmin ping -u root
/junk/mysqladmin.orig: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

$ mysqladmin ping -u myuser
mysqld is alive

$ mysqladmin ping
/junk/mysqladmin.orig: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

**new server**

```
$ mysqladmin ping -u root
/junk/mysqladmin.orig: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

$ mysqladmin ping -u myuser
mysqld is alive

$ mysqladmin ping
mysqld is alive
```

Comment: `mysqladmin ping` doesn't need a username or password. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Solarflare `mysqladmin ping` fails with `'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'`. I do not want `-u root` to work, and do not need to change passwords or usernames. I am trying to re-create the configuration on my current system which has a default username set somewhere so that running `mysqladmin ping` uses an username other than `root`.

Comment: @Solarflare Sorry if I'm not explaining this well. I've added a demonstration to the original post which hopefully makes my intention more clear.

Comment: I'm still not 100% if I understand, but you might want to check your `my.cfg` (look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) for a list for where this file can be stored, it can be in any (and several) of them). You can set default values (e.g. the username/(unencrypted)password), probably in the sections `[mysqladmin]` or `[client]`. Also, `~/.mylogin.cnf` can store (encrypted) login information. Your default values are probably somewhere in any of these files. But for ping, `mysqladmin ping -u userthatdoesntexist` works just fine, and is resistent to password change.

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you for the information. It lead me to realize that `myqladmin` itself has been modified on my original server, leading to this undocumented and unusual behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqladmin ping` has no "default user" or "default password" and should work even if the user and password are invalid. The behavior on this server is non-standard.

This is because mysqladmin has been sneakily replaced by the following bash wrapper:

```
$ cat `which mysqladmin`

#!/bin/bash
# wrapper to make our local MySQL work
#
# Where are we again?
case $0 in
         /*)  SHELLFILE=$0 ;;
        ./*)  SHELLFILE=${PWD}${0#.} ;;
        ../*) SHELLFILE=${PWD%/*}${0#..} ;;
          *)  SHELLFILE=$(type -P "$0") ; if [ "${SHELLFILE:0:1}" != "/" ]; then SHELLFILE="${PWD}/$SHELLFILE" ; fi ;;
esac

# readlink -m makes sure SHELLDIR is a simple absolute path
SHELLDIR=`readlink -m "${SHELLFILE%/*}"`

# Call the original mysqladmin with appropriate settings
${SHELLDIR}/mysqladmin.orig --protocol=TCP --port=4777 $*
```

in my case the fix is to open port 4777, but the general moral of the story is:

if `mysqladmin` (or any program) is behaving in an undocumented way then it is worth checking that the program has not been wrapped, aliased, or overloaded with a bash function (like in my other answer).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7 and above saves root in MySQL log file.

Please try this:

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

[You can follow the below link to set/reset MYSQL passwords](https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords)

Comment: the system I am recreating is not using the root user when running `mysqladmin ping`. There is some way it is running `mysqladmin ping` run with a different user and password without explicitly passing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary workaround, but it is certainly not ideal. `mysqladmin` can be overloaded with a bash function which appends the user/pass details.

I do not think this is how it is done on my old server, because I have already looked through `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc.

```
mysqladmin() {
         if [[ $@ == "ping" ]]; then
                 command mysqladmin ping -u myuser -p mypass
         else
                 command mysqladmin "$@"
         fi
}
```

this is bad because:

1. password stored in plaintext
2. does not work from other scripts which may not load this from your `.bashrc`
3. others may not realize you have modified the behavior of `mysqladmin`